# Sound only works when I am logged out

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS I have been unable to restore audio.
This is my first time using a linux based OS and I am only a beginner so I am still coming to grips with the OS.

When I am logged out the sound works but as soon as I log in the sound fails.

I am guessing it is related to the fact that I cannot see any of Additional Drivers in order to install the proprietary driver.

I have tried most of the usual alsamixer and pulse related troubleshoots but with no success.

Any suggestions to get the sound back up and running would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain how you know sound works when you are logged out?

Comment: I tried accessibility screen reader on the login screen and it worked.